# Evaluate the sum to $N$ terms of a $\sinh^{-1}$ function

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

This question has bugged me, I want to calculate the total number of turns $N$ that will give me a particular inductance $F_1$ due to a series of coil turns. I have a mathematical expression in terms of $N$, $i$, $W$, $L$, $a$, and $r$

$$F_1=\sum_{i=0}^N (-(L-(N-i)a)-r)\sinh^{-1}\left[\frac{(L-(N-i)a)-r}{W-(N-i)a)-r}\right]\\ -((W-(N-i)a)-r)\sinh^{-1}\left[\frac{(W-(N-i)a)-r}{L-(N-i)a)-r}\right]$$

I know the outmost length and width $L$ and $W$ of my coil, I also know a and $r$, which represent turn to turn spacing and wire thickness. **But how do I simplify this summation to get $N$ in terms of what I know, I want to get rid of the summation sign?** $N$ is unknown and $i$ is dependent on $N$ since it is summing from $1$ to $N$. I know this is a mathematical problem and I need help.

Comment: Please is anyone available to bring a suggestion to the above question?